# What do the parameters in tailwind `grid-cols-[1fr,700px,2fr]` do?

Tags: tailwind-css

I’m trying to understand tailwind grids better - could someone help me understand what each of the parameters `1fr`, `700px` and `2fr` do in

```
<!-- Complex grids -->
<div class="grid-cols-[1fr,700px,2fr]">
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To understand this, first you need to understand grid columns in general in CSS.

The code that you wrote translates to `grid-template-columns: 1fr 700px 2fr;` in pure CSS.

The `grid-template-columns` property specifies the number (and the widths) of columns in a grid layout.

CSS Syntax for `grid-template-columns` is this:

```css
grid-template-columns: none|auto|max-content|min-content|length|initial|inherit;
```

You can read here more about `grid-template-columns` and order of parameters:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns
- https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_grid-template-columns.asp

But in short, first parameter `1fr` means 1 fractional unit.

By definition Fr unit is a fractional unit and `1fr` is for 1 part of the available space.
The same goes for `2fr`.
`700px` just means 700 pixels.

That further means that code above produces 3 columns grid container, with the size for each column of `1fr`, `700px` & `2fr`.

How tailwind is doing that, you can read here:

- https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-template-columns#arbitrary-values
- https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#using-arbitrary-values

In short, tailwind uses arbitrary values to allow you to specify something that doesn’t make sense to include in your theme so you can use square brackets to generate a property on the fly using any arbitrary value.

Result of your code is something like this:

[image: grid-template-columns example]

You can play with this:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 700px 2fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container>div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head></head>

<body>

  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="item1">1fr</div>
    <div class="item2">700px</div>
    <div class="item3">2fr</div>
    <div class="item1">1fr</div>
    <div class="item2">700px</div>
    <div class="item3">2fr</div>
    <div class="item1">1fr</div>
    <div class="item2">700px</div>
    <div class="item3">2fr</div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```